# Movie about scientists that try to colonize a planet and the rescue of them

Tags: story-identification

We loosely remember some things about the movie. But it's based on memories so we may be wrong.
It was about some scientists that were sent on a distant planet to kind of rescue some other scientists that already have been there some time. Their job was to find a spot to colonize the planet. We think that each of the scientists sleep in some kind of cryostasis, and they are scattered over the planet. Maybe they search for water or some other habitable parameters. 
Different things went wrong and they find some scientists. Then they somehow have a decision to make between two scientists, one of them reports about very habitable conditions. So they decide to rescue this one and as it turns out, the scientist lied to them: He just wanted to be rescued. So in the end there are some fights on icy or rocky terrains.
Maybe the movie also involves a robot type that is kind of rectangular with a black display on it - but we are not sure about it.

Furthermore there may be some kind of relationships between the scientists, the rescued scientist and a woman of the rescue team were a couple.
In the end they quickly have to leave the planet - we don't know why.

Can anyone point us into the right direction ? :-(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is [**Interstellar**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/). Every single aspect you've described fits perfectly.

- **Scientists that were sent on a distant planet to kind of rescue some other scientists that already have been there some time.**

  **Check.** *Coop and a team of NASA Scientists set out to rescue [the "lazarus pilots"](https://youtu.be/td-2X0Xx4Xw?t=1m49s), a team of scientists who went ahead to detect whether planets were suitable for colonisation.*
- **We think that each of the scientists sleep in some kind of cryostasis, and they are scattered over the planet. Maybe they search for water or some other habitable parameters.**

  **Check.** *The cryopods land and the scientists get out so that they can perform basic research then relay it to a satellite. One of these checks is looking for habitable parameters.*
- **Different things went wrong and they find some scientists**

  **Check.** *Lots of things go wrong in their search for the scientists.*
- **Then they somehow have a decision to make between two scientists, one of them reports about very habitable conditions. So they decide to rescue this one and as it turns out, the scientist lied to them: He just wanted to be rescued.**

  **Check.** *This is precisely what happens. When choosing between Edmunds' World and Mann's World, they go for the one with the better readings. Those turn out to be false. Professor Mann [faked the results so that he could get rescued](https://youtu.be/2eO1jK5oETY?t=3m2s).*
- **So in the end there are some fights on icy or rocky terrains**

  **Check.** *[Mann fights with Coop on an icy terrain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyiu3FYH_io).*
- **Maybe the movie also involves a robot type that is kind of rectangular with a black display on it**

  **Check.** *[TARS and CASE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVEfFHzUby0) are both rectangular robots.*
- **In the end they quickly have to leave the planet - we don't know why.**

  **Check** - *[Mann steals the shuttle and Coop and the others need to chase him back into space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3lcGnMhvsA) before he can steal their ship and strand them.*
- **there may be some kind of relationships between the scientists, the rescued scientist and a woman of the rescue team were a couple.**

  **Check.** *One of the NASA scientists and Dr. Edmunds were in a relationship. It coloured her decision to vote for Edmunds' World over the obviously more suitable Mann's World.*

Comment: Oh. You really got us. The second story line and time shifts of the movie puzzled us very much I think. Thank you very much @Valorum

Answer (score 16):

Likely “Interstellar” from a couple of years ago. It has a stranded scientist who lies about conditions to be rescued.